# Capistrano SSHKit Execute Error

Tags: ruby, ssh, capistrano, capistrano3

I'm new to deploying using Capistrano and I don't know why I am receiving this kind of error. I need your insights about what is happening here and what are the possible solutions.

```
** Invoke sandbox (first_time)
** Execute sandbox
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke deploy (first_time)
** Execute deploy
** Invoke deploy:starting (first_time)
** Execute deploy:starting
** Invoke deploy:check (first_time)
** Invoke git:check (first_time)
** Invoke git:wrapper (first_time)
** Execute git:wrapper
00:00 git:wrapper
      01 mkdir -p /tmp
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as silicons@siliconserve.com: Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.16.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.16.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout: Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:90:in `rescue in initialize'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:56:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:237:in `new'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:237:in `start'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.16.0/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:59:in `call'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.16.0/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:59:in `with'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.16.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:176:in `with_ssh'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.16.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:129:in `execute_command'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.16.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.16.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `tap'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.16.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `create_command_and_execute'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.16.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:74:in `execute'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.10.1/lib/capistrano/scm/tasks/git.rake:8:in `block (3 levels) in eval_rakefile'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.16.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `instance_exec'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.16.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `run'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.16.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Errno::ETIMEDOUT: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2) for 78.46.114.60:22
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/socket.rb:64:in `connect'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/socket.rb:64:in `connect_internal'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/socket.rb:137:in `connect'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/socket.rb:627:in `block in tcp'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/socket.rb:227:in `each'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/socket.rb:227:in `foreach'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/socket.rb:617:in `tcp'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:70:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:237:in `new'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:237:in `start'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.16.0/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:59:in `call'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.16.0/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:59:in `with'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.16.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:176:in `with_ssh'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.16.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:129:in `execute_command'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.16.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.16.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `tap'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.16.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `create_command_and_execute'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.16.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:74:in `execute'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.10.1/lib/capistrano/scm/tasks/git.rake:8:in `block (3 levels) in eval_rakefile'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.16.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `instance_exec'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.16.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `run'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.16.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => deploy:check => git:check => git:wrapper
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as silicons@siliconserve.com: Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout
** Invoke deploy:failed (first_time)
** Execute deploy:failed
```

I've been figuring out this since this morning and I couldn't move on. Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your firewall is blocking port 22 on your domain (SSH).

Comment: Could you please explain more? Pretty please.

Comment: The domain (siliconserve.com) is not accepting connections on port 22.  It is not possible to troubleshoot further without knowing the OS and firewall configuration of the server for that domain.

Comment: You mean we could only deploy using port 22?